# resize bulk of images on 1280x 720 without cropping

Tags: php, image-size

I have 60 `jpg` images inside `img` folder
they are all of various dimensions
need all of them to be `1280` x `720`
white background - if needed
using this code spinner on page works obut 10 seconds - meaning the code works something - but final result is - nothing
each image has the same dimension as before
pls help

```
function resize_no_crop($el, $w, $h) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($el);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $newwidth = $h*$r;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        $newheight = $w/$r;
        $newwidth = $w;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($el);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    return $dst;
}

$arr = glob('img/*');
foreach($arr as $el){resize_no_crop($el, 1280, 720);}
echo 'finito';
```

Comment: From the perspective of someone not knowing PHP at all this looks like there is a function to change pictures but I cannot find a command to write the new picture to the disk. If this is a one off job, ImageMagick from the command line might be a valid alternative: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't saving the images:

```
$quality = 95;
foreach($arr as $el){
    // Destinazione
    $dest = dirname($el).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename($el, '.jpg') . '.cropped.jpg';

    $resized = resize_no_crop($el, 1280, 720);
    imagejpeg($resized, $dest, $quality);
}
```

Or you cal use `$dest = $el` to overwrite the original images (I never recommend this).

Answer (score 1):

Use Imagick resizeImage:

```php
foreach($arr as $el) {
    $im = new \Imagick();
    $im->readImage($el);
    $im->resizeImage(1280, 720, \Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);
    $im->writeImage($el);
    $im->destroy();
}
```

From documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php